# Push right column of array to right edge

Tags: equations, columns

although I am not new to LaTex, I am new to this forum which I have been appreciating since years - so thanks for all!

Here's my problem: I want to set an equation with basically two columns -  formulas on the left and some relevant space definitions on the right. Every of the two columns could have multiple, but different numbers of rows whilst the whole columns should be centered vertically to each other.  The whole block should only have one equation number (so far I think I achieved that - but open for suggestions).

But I can't find a solution for the following: How can I automatically push (for usage in a general environment) the right column (which has a variable width) to the right edge of the page, while the entries in the  left column are centered in the left over space?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

   \begin{equation}
      \begin{array}{rcr}
      \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} z = f(z) 
      \hspace*{\fill}
      &\begin{array}{rl}
      z \in &\mathbb{R}\\
      f:   &\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R} 
      \end{array}
      \end{array}

\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I am happy for every help, also for the existing code. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! And where should the equation number go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?
[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
      &&
      \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} z = f(z) 
      &&\begin{aligned}
        z \in &\mathbb{R}\\
        f:   &\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R} 
      \end{aligned}
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

---

If I understand you correctly, you want to overlap the equation number.

[image: demo2]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
      &&
      \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} z = f(z) 
      &&\mathrlap{\hphantom{~(\theequation)}%
        \mathllap{\begin{aligned}
        z \in &\mathbb{R}\\
        f:   &\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R} 
      \end{aligned}}}
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh pefect! That's what I wanted - with the equation right in the middle on the right side. 
Can you tell me what the double ampersand does?

Comment: The first ampersand is an alignment point, the second adds a gap.  Then it repeats.

Comment: :-) You never stop learning. Thank you! I've got a follow up question: 
How could I push the definition block to the right (as it is in the upper example) and center the main equation in the middle with respect to the page and not the left-over space.

Comment: There are two ways to center using flalign.  You can use `\phantom` to add space to the left or use `\mathllap` to hide the space to the right.